# Use a specific Spring profile for `mvn test` by default

Tags: java, spring, maven

**How can I configure the Maven `test` phase to use, *by default*, a Spring [profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) named `test`?**

In other words, I want a plain invocation of `mvn test` (with no other arguments) to default to using the Spring profile named `test`. Currently, `mvn test` uses the `default` profile (to no surprise).

As a second requirement, I would like for developers to be able to override this at the command line using e.g.:

```bash
mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=otherprofile
```

and for that to take precedence over the default `test` profile.

I would expect this to be configurable in `pom.xml`, but haven't been able to find what I'm looking for in the Maven docs.

---

Note: my test framework here is JUnit 5 and test classes are annotated with `SpringBootTest`, though I don't think that should be relevant here.

Comment: If you need to active a profile you should use `@ActiveProfiles(..)` for a particular test... instead of giving that via command line apart from that it does not work, because the `spring.profiles.active` is for the spring boot application itself...btw. why not adding the a particular `application.yaml` in`src/test/resources` which can active a profile as well ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have multiple test classes. It seems pretty sub-optimal to have to decorate all of them with that annotation - can't it be configured from one place? Secondly: I already have multiple profiles in resources/application.yml, one of them being `test`.  Lastly, `mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=test` does in fact do exactly what I want, which is to activate the `test` profile for the Spring app.

Comment: Also: Using `@ActiveProfiles` does not allow me to override from the command line as I have specified. The annotation takes precedence.

Comment: Where have you located the `application.yml`? In `src/test/resources`? Also why do you need to overwrite your test profiles via cli?

Comment: Located at `src/main/resources/application.yml` and is being read correctly (that is not the issue here).  I need to offer the option to overwrite the profile in use with `mvn test` so that developers can choose between environments used when testing.

Comment: Giving an `application.yml` (for exmaple with multi doc) or using `application-test.properites` into `src/test/resources` can be used to define profile in tests only ... either overwrite or replace them completely .. .much easier than configuration/cli arguments etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I've already used multi-doc YAML in `src/main/resources/application.yml` to define multiple Spring profiles. This question is about _activating_ a particular Spring profile when running a specific Maven phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `plugin:goal` for the Maven `test` phase is `surefire:test`, we can configure the Maven Surefire plugin:

```xml
  <build>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=test</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
...
```

Then, `mvn test` will run by default with the Spring `test` profile, but can be also overriden:

```bash
mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=other
```

Comment: your solution works assuming you use maven surefire plugin. The one I provided will work regardless.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on version of maven you use. But assuming you can use the latest version of maven you can add this in your  `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/jvm.config`:

```
 -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

Then the command line you specified will override it.

If you haven't done it yet you can have read about [maven config](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html)